# SWI Prolog: How to view a pre-built predicate code?

Tags: prolog, predicate, swi-prolog

I am interesting in how some predicates are built like `downcase_atom/2`. Is there a way to view the predicate code ?

Comment: All of the SWI Prolog source is available from [their website](http://www.swi-prolog.org/). Just check the DOWNLOAD link.

Answer (score 6):

You can start by looking into the predicate properties:

```
?- predicate_property(downcase_atom(_,_), P).
P = visible ;
P = built_in ;
P = foreign ;
P = imported_from(system) ;
P = nodebug ;
false.
```

This tells you that the predicate is imported from the `system` module. If you look into this module properties:

```
?- module_property(system, P).
P = class(system) ;
P = exports([]) ;
P = program_size(113424) ;
false.
```

you will see that there isn't any source file associated to the module. So, in this case, you will need to look into the sources of SWI-Prolog itself. You will find that the predicate is defined in C code in the file `src/os/pl-ctype.c`. In other cases, system predicates may be defined in Prolog code, in which case the steps above may give you the name and location of the source files defining them.

Comment: I hope it is also possible to [obtain the source code of user-defined predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556721/printing-the-source-code-of-a-predicate-in-prolog).